# reference not found in xsd

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jdeveloper

Please helpe me, I know this is a very simple problem still need help.
Please refer the follwing schema..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/RegistrationUpload_jws/RegistrationUpload/Taskprocess"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <complexType name="officer" id="officer"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <sequence>
               <element name="mainOfficer" type="string"/>
               <element name="mainOfficerId" type="string"/>
               <element name="coveringOfficer" type="string"/>
               <element name="coveringOfficerId" type="string"/>
               <element name="defaultOfficer" type="string"/>
               <element name="defaultOfficerId" type="string"/>
               <element name="matrixId" type="string"/>
          </sequence>
     </complexType>
     <element name="process">
          <complexType>
               <sequence>
                    <element name="input" id="officer" type="officer" nillable="false"
                             maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
               </sequence>
          </complexType>
     </element>
     <element name="processResponse">
          <complexType>
               <sequence>
                    <element name="result" type="string"/>
               </sequence>
          </complexType>
     </element>
</schema>
```

I am getting the problem reference office not found(using Jdeveloper)

Comment: Can you provide more info on the error? When exactly do you get it? Any chance your XML-File doesn't match the XSD?

Comment: Thanks, I have pasted the whole XML file content.. The problem is I am using Jdeveloper for creating BPEL process. so when we create BPEL automatically xsd file will be created, then my requirement was to make the input parameter complex type. so i changed in xsd and found this error.... THE ERROR IS 'REFERENCE FOR OFFICER IS NOT FOUND' Hope to hear from you...

Comment: You first said the problem name is "office", then you said it is "OFFICER". Actually, it is "officer". Getting basic information like this wrong makes it much more difficult for people to help you. Please try harder.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is namespace related. The default namespace of the document is `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` which means that you can refer to XML built in types without a prefix, as in `type="string"`. However, the type `officer` lives in the target name space, so when you refer to that type you must qualify it using a namespace binding. Add this to the `schema`element:

```
xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/RegistrationUpload_jws/RegistrationUpload/Taskprocess"
```

and use the tns prefix when referring to the officer type:

```
<element name="input" type="tns:officer" nillable="false" ... />
```

(Also, the use of the id attribute is odd, especially since you have duplicate content.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same, and error was removed. but an additional error was comes in my wsdl file for elements 'processResponse' and 'process'. do i need to change in wsdl file also.

Comment: Hard to tell without more info.